# how to handle syntax errors in node-sass-middleware

Tags: node.js, express, sass, node-sass

I am using node-sass-middleware in an Express 4 app to compile SCSS files. Works great but then I leave out a semi colon and my Express page just hangs because it won't compile the SCSS.

How I can I view any errors that might exist after I make changes before making the site live because I can't have a production site hanging?